# How can I change a bootstrap component prop's type values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

im pretty new to typescript. I have a component props which have type '"sm" | "lg" | undefined'. Instead of just sm and lg, how can i achieve to add more enum values such as "xs", "md', "xl"?

//edited
So i have  and i have props.size from parent component. props.size has type of enum Size, which is different to predefined types of props.size from . How can i change the predefined types?

example:

```
declare type InputType = "text" | "password" | " number" | "email"

interface CustomInputProps{
    size: InputType
}
```

```
const CustomInput: React.FC<CustomInputProps> = (props)=>(
    <Form.Control size={props.size} />
)
```

my problem is that Form.Control.size type is has only "sm" and "lg", and i cannot add "md" or there will be linting error.

Comment: It's stil unclear what kind of properties you are talking about. Can you provide a conrete exmaple with code? what components are you using? What  props are you trying to use?

Comment: @IgorGonak i have added example

Comment: I think I start to understand what you try to achieve - do you want to set the size of the Form.Control depending on the type you have? For example if type=text then size=lg or when type=email then size=sm etc? Or do you want to have more size variants?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more options to an existing union type by declaring a new type and adding options to it.

```
// imported from some library probably
type BootstrapSize = 'sm' | 'lg'

type MySize = BootstrapSize | 'xs' | 'md' | 'xl'

const a: MySize = 'sm' // works
const b: MySize = 'xl' // works
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=23&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nYBnYAnAhmAygSwF7QC8UA5EgLYlQA+pANgOYkBQokUAsiLgVMfIhQZs+aLRIAPJFXHkAJjNIS6LZgGM4AOxRR0ALk7dRfUhRYbtwKACMDXHkSUqgA)

Comment: I think i worded my question wrongly. So i have <BootstrapComponent /> and i  have props.size, from parent component. props.size has type of enum Size, which is different to predefined types of props.size from <BootstrapComponent/>. How can i change the predefined types?

Comment: Can u provide an example?